# The file is too large - why does the file size limit differ on each computer?

Tags: r, error-handling, version, filesize

There is a file size limit implemented in R-Studio. I have an R-file with a size of 3.3MB. On my computer the limit is set to 5MB and therefore I can open my R-file without any problems. However, I just tried to open the file on another computer and there the file size limit is set to 2MB. For that reason, I receive the error message: The file `xxx` is too large to open in the source editor.

I am wondering, why the file size limit differs on different computers. Could it be because of the version of R? I am using version 3.2.1 and on the other computer version 3.1.2 is used.

***Question 1: Why does R-Studio have different file size limits on different computers?***

***Question 2: If it is because of the version of R, is there a list of file size limits for each version of R available?***

Comment: Thanks for your hint @ Roman Lustrik. The file consists of 40.000 lines of code. Unfortunately there is no easy way to make the code more efficient or to separate the file.

Comment: Btw, I am able to work around the problem, if I open the file in R and then copy the code to R-Studio. I would like to avoid this procedure, if possible, but if there is no other way I will keep doing that.

Comment: The source editor has nothing (AFAIK) to do with the version of R (which is just a programming language, not a development environment). It might depend on the version or settings of *RStudio* (which is the component that implements the source file editor).

Comment: Thank you @ Ben Bolker. Good to know that it is probably not related with  the R version. Unfortunately I can not find anything in the settings of R-Studio as well.

Comment: if you don't get an answer here you might try in the RStudio support forums.